# How to avoid redeclaring class method parameter types in subclass in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a subclass that extends an abstract superclass in a different file. The code below in `implementation.ts` fails TS typecheck for `doStrangeThing()` as I am required to re-declare the parameter types (string,IComplexOptions). I am hoping to avoid the extra import and verbiage. Can anyone point out how it can be done (if possible)?

It seems intuitive the compiler should infer the method signature from the superclass especially if an abstract one, or at least take that as default if missing. Is there some way I am missing to do this (notwithstanding complications like trying to overload methods, or union types), or at least some way to extract the Parameter, or some way to hint the compiler to inherit the signature from the super?

```js
//
// baseClasses.ts
//
import {IComplexOptions} from './foo';

abstract class Animal {
  abstract name: string;
  abstract doStrangeThing( action:string, options:IComplexOptions ):void;
}

//
// implementation.ts
//
import {Animal} from './baseClasses';

class Rhino extends Animal {
  name="Rhino";
  doStrangeThing(action,options){  // <== TS error here, implicit 'any'

  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript incorrect type inference when class implements interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256115/typescript-incorrect-type-inference-when-class-implements-interface)

Comment: @AlekseyL. not really, that one is about implements for an interface, mine is a direct extend of a (super)class.

Comment: The rules are the same (doesn't matter interface or base class). Have a look at linked issues in accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to actually avoid redeclaring arguments' types since Typescript implements structural inheritance.

As a workaround, you can use the `Parameters` utility type to extract the parameters from another interface. This is useful when using a single object as a function parameter (vs positional parameters) and you have methods whose arguments might change frequently.

For example:

```typescript
interface Foo {
  method(args: { arg1: string, arg2: number}): void;
}

class Bar implements Foo {
  method({ arg1, arg2 }: Parameters<Foo['method']>[0]): void {
    // arg1 and arg2 types will be correctly inferred
  }
}
```

If you have several methods to redeclare, you can create your own utility type for a particular class:

```typescript
interface Foo {
  method(args: { arg1: string, arg2: number}): void;
}

type FooArgs<Method extends keyof Foo> = Parameters<Foo[Method]>[0];

class Bar implements Foo {
  method({ arg1, arg2 }: FooArgs<'method'>): void {
    // arg1 and arg2 types will be correctly inferred
  }
}
```