# Typescript: How to avoid repeating object declaration as a parameter?

Tags: typescript

## Motivation

I would liked to use object as a function parameter. This allow the caller to clearly define the arguments with the field names specified making reviews easier.

## Problem

However, this is not very nice to deal with if you use `implements` and `extends`. This is what I am doing now.

`src/domain/ServiceInterface.ts`

```typescript
export interface ServiceInterface {
  doesThings(args: {
    awesomeFieldName: string;
    isThisAwesomeFieldName?: string;
    ohWaitMoreAwesomeFieldName?: string;
  }): boolean;
```

`src/domain/ComposedServiceInterface.ts`

```typescript
import { ServiceInterface } from "./domain/ServiceInterface";
export type ComposedServiceInterface = ServiceInterface & { hello: () => string };
```

`src/implementations/ComposedServiceImplementation.ts`

```typescript
import { ComposedServiceInterface } from "./domain/ComposedServiceInterface";
export class ComposedServiceImplementation implements ComposedServiceInterface {
  doesThings(args: {
    awesomeFieldName: string;
    isThisAwesomeFieldName?: string;
    ohWaitMoreAwesomeFieldName?: string;
  }): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

## Attempts

### 1. Using `type` / `interface` for the object parameter

`src/domain/ServiceInterface.ts`

```typescript
export type DoesThingsParameter = {
    awesomeFieldName: string;
    isThisAwesomeFieldName?: string;
    ohWaitMoreAwesomeFieldName?: string;
  };
export interface ServiceInterface {
  doesThings(args: DoesThingsParameter): boolean;
```

`src/domain/ComposedServiceInterface.ts`

```typescript
import { ServiceInterface } from "./domain/ServiceInterface";
export type ComposedServiceInterface = ServiceInterface & { hello: () => string };
```

`src/implementations/ComposedServiceImplementation`

```typescript
import { ComposedServiceInterface } from "./domain/ComposedServiceInterface";
import { DoesThingsParameter } from "./domain/ServiceInterface";
export class ComposedServiceImplementation implements ComposedServiceInterface {
  doesThings(args: DoesThingsParameter): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Gripe: I don't like this implemetation because `src/implementations/ComposedServiceImplementation` should not need to `import` from `src/domain/ServiceInterface` since it only implements `ComposedServiceInterface`

### 2. Using `Parameter` Utility Type

ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype

I can't seem to get typescript to agree using a Class method e.g. `Parameter<ComposedServiceInterface.doesThings>`

Can someone offer any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of reusing types/interfaces is Attemp#1. Whenever you need to reuse some type definitions, you can extract it out. If you are concerned about importing from `src/domain/ServiceInterface` in `src/implementations/ComposedServiceImplementation`, you can always create a common file for types and add common types there and import in both of the files.

The one point to notice here is that you are only importing types from `src/domain/ServiceInterface` so this import will be cleaned away after you compile your TS code. If you want to know whether you are importing a type of a value, you can use type only import like:
`import type { DoesThingsParameter } from "./domain/ServiceInterface";`
This will give your code more readability.

About Attemp#2, Try to avoid using complex utility types like `Parameter` or `ConstructorParameter` too frequently as their implementation is quite complex and Typescript has to do a lot of work. These types are generally used to get types for args for which you don't have access directly.
For example, if you are using a library that doesn't ship typescript definitions and you want to use a function from this library.

```js
// some-library.ts
export function configure({
 config1 = 'somevalue',
 retries = 1
}) {
  ...code
}
```

Now you want to use this `configure` function but want to create a configuration object outside.

```
// helper.ts
import { configure } from 'some-lib';

const configuration = {
 config1: 'overrideValue',
 unknownProperty: 'unknownValue'
}
function helper() {
 const lib = configure(configuration)
...some work here
 }
```

Now, the configuration has all the properties that the `configure` function needs but it has added one new property that doesn't exist in `configure` args. In this case, you have to use ParameterType to get the type definition of `configure` args.

Comment: I don't think Typescript allows inferring types from an `implements` clause. So you have to make it match, or have a type error. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256115/typescript-incorrect-type-inference-when-class-implements-interface