# Why my class method is not able to get the params types from its interface?

Tags: typescript

I wrote this code below to show my problem

```js
type MyFunction<T> = (req: string, res: number) => T;

interface ITest {
  store: MyFunction<void>;
}

class Test implements ITest {
  store(req, res) { //req, res got implicit any type
      req.codePointAt()
      res.toFixed()
  }
}
```

Why when I implement my interface ITest on my class Test it still not being able to infer the params types ?

Comment: I don’t have time to answer now but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256115/typescript-incorrect-type-inference-when-class-implements-interface … the implements clause in an interface just acts as a type check; it does not participate in type inference. The linked question’s answer points to some GitHub issues around the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ITest.store` must implement `(req: string, res: number) => void;`. Your Test's `store` method technically does that. Its signature is `(req: any, res:any) => void`. The `any` types both suffice for `string` and `number`.

When you use `implements`, your object/class/etc is agreeing to fulfill the interface's requirements. **This means the interface isn't making any decisions about the types**. Its the responsibility of the implementor. So back to above, `Test` agrees to implement the `ITest` interface. Its store method currently has a signature of `(req: any, res: any) => void`. Since `any` fulfills `string` and `number` it effectively fulfills the `ITest` interface.

Comment: Is there something that I can do to infer my param types on my interface ?

Comment: Not without typing it. However, you have a type handy already. @Balastrong has an example of utilizing the type MyFunction to minimize duplication.

Comment: okay, thank you for your answer, it was very helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

`store` is not a function, is a property that has a type that is a function.

If you want to keep the type, you should declare it like so:

```js
    class Test implements ITest {
      store: MyFunction<void> = (req, res) => {
          req.codePointAt();
          res.toFixed();
      }
    }
```

And now `codePointAt` wants a parameter :)

Comment: What's the difference (in TypeScript) between a method and a property that holds a function?

Comment: This looks like a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39156471/6303541

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what @jcalz meant, you still need to put the param and return type on the class method, but by implementing a interface, TypeScript will check whether the method have the same param and return type as the interface it implements

```
type MyFunction<T> = (req: string, res: number) => T;

interface ITest {
  store: MyFunction<void>;
}

class Test implements ITest {
  store(req: number, res: number): void {
  }
}
```

that code will shows an error because `req` type is incompatible

```
Property 'store' in type 'Test' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ITest'.
  Type '(req: number, res: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'MyFunction<void>'.
    Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbIDwBUA+KAXigAoAnCARwC4oBnYSjZAcwBoprGHlEAWwBGESgEpSxfAG4AsAChFbYGIBmAQ1TQAkvgjMoAb0VQmwLNQZwkaTDlwA3LBgAmheQrPNLEAEzWCCjo2HjObh6KAL6KiqgANhqMjFD6hhiCYPEQghDIwCl6BsDGpua+VLT8QqKU3LzVImLiDOGupV5mXQD03VBilJZlMUqdPtR+lfTmrBz1Bo21LVBtHV09fchY-ZSDlMPRQA)

Comment: That error is appearing because your type for req is number but the MyFunction type uses string. I don't believe its related to the original question.

Comment: That's the point of my answer, I'm just clarifying what @jcalz said; "the implements clause in an interface just acts as a type check; it does not participate in type inference", which answers the question "Why my class method is not able to get the params types from its interface?",  and the code I provided (especially the one at the TS Playground) is just an example to prove that

Comment: Ah I see now. Thanks!